# Twitter bootstrap button dropdowns btn-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want that the dropdown buttons also can go over the whole page like buttons with the class btn-block. Here my current code : http://jsfiddle.net/wLUkx/1/

Here the code:

```
    <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large dropdown-lead dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
   xx
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-play">
            <button class="btn btn-link">xx</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-newgame">
            <button class="btn btn-link">xx</button>
        </form>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-joingame">
            <button class="btn btn-link">xx</button>
        </form>
    </ul>

    </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large dropdown-lead dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    yyy
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-play">
            <button class="btn btn-link">yyy</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-newgame">
            <button class="btn btn-link">yyy</button>
        </form>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-joingame">
            <button class="btn btn-link">yyy</button>
        </form>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="game" value="paint">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">paint</button>
</form>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class '**btn-group**' has a property of `display:inline-block`. Changing this to `display: block` should give you the desired effect.

Comment: it works but the second button-group has at the left free space. Why? http://jsfiddle.net/wLUkx/2/

Comment: Remove this from bootstrap.css: `.btn-group + .btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}`.  That is what is causing the space.

Answer (score 9):

Add `btn-block` to `<div class="btn-group">`

Comment: This worked for me, but note I needed the class on *both* the `btn-group` and the `btn` itself

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <button type="button" style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    actions <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="btn-group-justified"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="btn-group-justified"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="btn-group-justified"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="btn-group-justified"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLUkx/14/ (but for twitter bootstrap 3.x verison)

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, a code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would describe what the code is doing differently, tell where the code gets inserted, and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller http://jsfiddle.net/wLUkx/14/ (but for twitter bootstrap 3.x verison)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css `.btn-group{display:block;}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the buttons in that fiddle, its the containers. The 'btn-group' class is inline and it is making the buttons the minimum width they can be. You can either remove 'btn-group' from those containers or create a new class that makes them "width:100%;"

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding `btn-block` to **both** `<div class="btn-group"` and `<a class="btn">`

I discovered the solution [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4779#issuecomment-21628426)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large dropdown-lead dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        xx
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-play">
            <button class="btn btn-link">xx</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-newgame">
            <button class="btn btn-link">xx</button>
        </form>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="game" value="ttt-joingame">
            <button class="btn btn-link">xx</button>
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```